# Any C project that use antlr3?

Tags: c, antlr, antlr3

I am a java programmer and currently learning antlr3.

I have to use antlr in a C project. 
It is a little difficult for a java programmer to write C code use antlr.

So, I want to look some C project that use antlr

I find a lot of java project that use antlr, eg. hive, esper 
but I could not find a C project.

anyone know a C project that use antlr3?
Thank you in advance..

Comment: Posted [here](http://antlr.markmail.org/search/?q=#query:+page:1+mid:oesy4aiezzkvttyq+state:results) too.

Comment: @BartKiers thank you.. I first asked here, then I asked in the antlr mail list... One of the mail-list user told me that tora http://sourceforge.net/projects/tora/?_test=beta is using antlr3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some BSD-licensed C++ code which uses an ANTLR3-generated C parser: [AST traversal](http://code.google.com/p/foster/source/browse/compiler/parse/ANTLRtoFosterAST.cpp?r=ff9586c649c887e67e9cb8065c7419dac08c4cda),  [error handling](http://code.google.com/p/foster/source/browse/compiler/parse/ANTLRtoFosterErrorHandling.cpp?r=2bd9753dc2bc11bbab1b8e00ded3282a819a48aa).